# Embed PDF losslessly in .docx file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, docx, embedding

Is there a way to embed a multi-page PDF in a `.docx` document so that

- it can be extracted (=saved to a file) "as is" later on
- the extraction process can be described easily?

This is for handing graphics in their original format to a publisher who requires a submission in Word format. I assume they will be able to handle PDFs, and I don't want to rasterize the images in case they want to rescale them.

I know that a `.docx` document is essentially a ZIP file, and that I could probably hide any content there. But the extraction process is not that easy to explain. Also, I'm not sure where to hide it so that Word does not complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in your Word document, place your cursor where you want to attach the file(s). Then click on the "Insert" tab at the top. Click on "Object" and then select the "Create from file" Or "PDF file" tab.
 "Browse" and select the file you want to attach and then check the "Display as icon" box. Finally, click the "OK" button. That should do it.

To extract it, Double-click on the "icon" in the word document - it will open in the end user's default PDF viewer. I assume that the recipient will be able to save the document using their default viewer, using file--> Save as but since the end user's PDF viewer is not specified, I cannot be  more specific.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I save this object back to disk?

Comment: Double-click on the "icon" in the word document - it will open in the end user's default PDF viewer.  I assume that the recipient will be able to save the document using their default viewer.

Comment: I tested with Adobe Professional. I didn't manage to save it...

Comment: In acrobat, click "file" --> save-as --> PDF.  I hope your recipient is using Acrobat......

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work last time I checked. Thanks so much for the detailed writeup!

Comment: It's the "display as icon" check box that gets most folks.  Glad it's working for you!